# Is it a game recommendation?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was very curious and asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61655/are-the-actions-in-kinect-games-predefined) to get any game name (so that I can google it myself later). Is it considered a game recommendation question?

I asked it because I have only seen other kind of games **in videos**, not those I was asking about.

Answer (score 6):

It falls under `Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)` in the [FAQ's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) list of prohibited question categories.